# algorithm for making optimise string from sub strings

Tags: c++, c, string, algorithm

Suppose I have a collection of substrings, for example:

```
string a = {"cat","sensitive","ate","energy","tense"}
```

Then the output for this should be as follows:

```
catensesensitivenergy
```

How can I do this?

Comment: In what language? Is this just a theoretical question (e.g. the kind you'd find in schoolwork) for which the language doesn't matter much?

Comment: What are the rules for constructing the string? Maximum overlap of substrings?

Comment: to be very specific language does not matter.

Comment: we can use native language c. The reason behind asking for algorithm is there should be not or minimum use of function, we can use stdin.h and stdio.h function

Comment: maximum optimization required for new string which is build on all small sub string.

Comment: Should the output actually be `catensensitivenergy`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [build shortest string from a collection of its subsequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107487/build-shortest-string-from-a-collection-of-its-subsequence)

Comment: AndyG it is not required to be exactly output ! keep in mind just maximum optimization..

Comment: there's no standard `string` type in C

Comment: You may be interested in http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is known as the shortest common superstring problem and it is NP-hard, so if you need an exact solution you cannot do much better then trying all possibilities and choosing the best one.

One possible exponential solution is to generate all permutations of the input strings, find the shortest common superstring greedily for each permutation(a permutation specifies the order of strings and it is possible to prove that for a fixed order greedy algorithm always works correctly) and choose the best one.

Comment: @AndyG supersequence and superstring are different things, actually.

Comment: "So you cannot do much better than trying all possibilities and choosing the best one." This is an over-simplification of what NP-hard means. Often totally exhaustive solutions can be beaten quite well, albeit not in provable polynomial time, e.g. for factoring integers which may very well be an NP-hard problem yet there are known solutions that are provably so much faster than trial division.

Comment: To be more specific, the problem at hand is NP-hard because it reduces to finding the shortest hamiltonian path in a directed graph

Answer (score 3):

Using user2040251 suggestion:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

std::string merge_strings( const std::vector< std::string > & pool )
{
    std::string retval;
    for( auto s : pool )
        if( retval.empty() )
            retval.append( s );
        else if( std::search( retval.begin(), retval.end(), s.begin(), s.end() ) == retval.end() )
        {
            size_t len = std::min( retval.size(), s.size() ); 
            for( ; len; --len )
                if( retval.substr( retval.size() - len ) == s.substr( 0, len ) )
                {
                    retval.append( s.substr( len ) );
                    break;
                }
            if( !len )
                retval.append( s );
        }
    return retval;           
}

std::string shortest_common_supersequence( std::vector< std::string > & pool )
{
    std::sort( pool.begin(), pool.end() );

    std::string buffer;
    std::string best_reduction = merge_strings( pool );
    while( std::next_permutation( pool.begin(), pool.end() ) )
    {
        buffer = merge_strings( pool );
        if( buffer.size() < best_reduction.size() )
            best_reduction = buffer;
    }
    return best_reduction;
}


int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    std::vector< std::string > a{"cat","sensitive","ate","energy","tense"};
    std::vector< std::string > b{"cat","sensitive","ate","energy","tense","sit"};
    std::vector< std::string > c{"personal","ate","energy","tense","gyroscope"};
    std::cout << "best a --> \"" << shortest_common_supersequence( a ) << "\"\n";
    std::cout << "best b --> \"" << shortest_common_supersequence( b ) << "\"\n";
    std::cout << "best c --> \"" << shortest_common_supersequence( c ) << "\"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
best a --> "catensensitivenergy"
best b --> "catensensitivenergy"
best c --> "atensenergyroscopersonal"
```

Comment: By checking every permutation arent you suboptimal ? Most of the time the _underlying graph_ of the words won't be complete making our life a bit easier :)

Answer (score 1):

Break the problem down and see what we got. Starting with only two strings. We must check which suffix of one string is the longest prefix of the other. This gives us the order for the best concatenation.

Now, with a set of *n* word, how do we do ? We start by building a **trie** containing every word (a key for each word). If a word is a duplicate of an other we can easily flag it as such while building the prefix tree.

I made a quick implementation of a regular Trie. You can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/Rerito/6e1af875f7b4980b3c11).

We have the tools to build a *directed graph* linking the different words wether a suffix of the first is a prefix of the second. The weight of the edge is the length of the suffix.

To do so, for each word *w* of the input set, we must see which words we can reach with a suffix of *w* :

- We walk down the trie using the suffix. We will end up in a node (or not).
- From this node, provided it exists, we scan the remaining subtree to see which words are
  available.

  - If a given suffix of length *l* yields a match with a
    prefix of word *w'*, then we add an edge *w → w'*, with weight *length(w') - l*.
  - If such an edge already exists, we just update the weight to keep the *lowest*.

From there, the graph is set and we must find the shortest path that runs through every vertex (eg. word) **only once**. If the graph is complete, this is the [*Traveling Salesman Problem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). Most of the times, the graph won't be complete.

Still, it remains a NP-hard problem. In more *"technical"* terms, the problem at hand is to find [*the shortest hamiltonian path* of a *digraph*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem).

*Note : Given an Hamiltonian path (if it exists) with its cost C, and its starting vertex (word) W, the supestring length is given by :*

> L<sub>*super*</sub> = L<sub>*W*</sub> + C

*Note : If two words have no suffix linking them to another word, then the graph is not connected and there is no hamiltonian path.*